# Add Cookie to jQuery Pop-Up Lightbox

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup, lightbox

Here is my test page - http://mymsaa.org/lightbox_test/

I have my pop-up lightbox working.

I need to add a cookie to the lightbox so it only appears once say every 15 days.

This is a new lightbox I am using so I am not that familiar with the code.

Here is the FULL code that I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/themes/dw-focus/assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript</noscript>   
<script src="http://mymsaa.org/lightbox_test/src/ezmodal.js"></script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript</noscript>          
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mymsaa.org/lightbox_test/src/ezmodal.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--LIGHTBOX-->                    
<div class="ezmodal" ezmodal-autoopen="true">
<div class="ezmodal-container">

<!--IFRAME FORM-->                                            
<div id='subscribe_popup' style='overflow: hidden; overflow-y:hidden;'>
<div style="padding: 10px;">
<iframe src="http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/themes/dw-focus/video_register/iframe/iframe.php" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="pop"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!--IFRAME FORM--> 

<div class="ezmodal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn1" data-dismiss="ezmodal">Skip Registration</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!--LIGHTBOX-->     

<!--IFRAME CSS-->
<style type="text/css">

#subscribe_popup { width: 470px; height: 380px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y:hidden; }

#subscribe_popup iframe { width: 446px; height: 380px; }

/*992px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 470px;}
}

/*768px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 470px;}

}

/*480px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 280px; height: 420px; margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}

#subscribe_popup iframe { width: 250px; height: 400px; }

}

/*320px*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

#subscribe_popup { width: 280px; height: 420px; margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}

#subscribe_popup iframe { width: 250px; height: 400px; }

}

</style>
<!--IFRAME CSS-->

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean scelerisque     malesuada ligula, id cursus diam facilisis ac. Sed id pulvinar mauris. Phasellus ac arcu velit. Cras tempor vestibulum volutpat. Proin consectetur lectus elementum imperdiet congue. Quisque quis nunc libero. Praesent gravida urna metus, ut elementum arcu posuere quis. Suspendisse mattis, enim vitae semper porta, metus mauris dignissim lorem, non eleifend risus mauris non diam. Ut in ullamcorper tortor, eu lobortis nibh.<p>

<p>Ut quis lectus sit amet tortor tempus imperdiet. Maecenas enim lacus, hendrerit ac volutpat quis, ornare eu diam. Maecenas nec odio odio. Aenean eu lectus lacinia, luctus mi non, placerat metus. Proin id tortor nec est suscipit ullamcorper sed eu metus. Donec efficitur, massa eu sagittis vehicula, magna erat gravida elit, dapibus vehicula tellus dolor sed purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor vel tellus vitae congue. Proin tincidunt quam velit, at posuere odio lobortis sit amet. Etiam posuere condimentum leo, a auctor elit sollicitudin nec. Vivamus faucibus tortor rhoncus orci fermentum, vitae efficitur orci mattis. Nunc est nunc, euismod vel magna vitae, fermentum dapibus libero. Maecenas quis erat aliquam enim scelerisque scelerisque sed vel metus. Sed eget finibus justo, consequat ornare sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
```

I know that I have...

```
ezmodal-autoopen="true"
```

in my code so it is opening every page load, but that was the only way I could get the lightbox to come up.

I have worked with cookies before on another light box and below is the code that I used before, when I try to apply it to this it does not work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$("document").ready(function (){ 
$("#skipbutton").click(function() {
$("#colorbox").fadeOut(300);
$('#cboxOverlay').remove();

});

if (document.cookie.indexOf('MSAAvideo_register_lightbox_WP_live=true') == -1) {
var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
document.cookie = "MSAAvideo_register_lightbox_WP_live=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
$.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
}

$(".open_popup").colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
 });

</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support Javascript</noscript>
```

Comment: Set auto open to false to start. Then check for cookie, if no cookie, trigger ezmodal to open via JS. Here is an article on cookies w. JS. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: How do I trigger ezmodal to open via JS?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with PHP.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "MSAAEmailSignUpForm_New";
$cookie_value = "MSAA";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 1), "/"); //     86400 = 1 day

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo "
<!--LIGHTBOX-->      

<div class=\"ezmodal\" ezmodal-autoopen=\"true\">
<div class=\"ezmodal-container\">

<!--IFRAME FORM-->                                            
<div id='subscribe_popup' style='overflow: hidden; overflow-y:hidden;'>
<div style=\"padding: 10px;\">
<iframe src=\"http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/themes/dw-focus/video_register/iframe/iframe.php\" border=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" name=\"pop\"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!--IFRAME FORM--> 

<div class=\"ezmodal-footer\">
<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn1\" data-dismiss=\"ezmodal\">Skip Registration</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!--LIGHTBOX-->";
} else {
echo "";

}
?>
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution.